# Linux Process State Code 'I'

Tags: linux, kernel, ps

I am new to linux kernel.
I just saw kernel states with `ps ax`.
And I saw the manual with `man ps` and google.

Finally I could not find what STAT `I` denotes for.
A lot of kworkers or filesystems are in this `I` state.
So, I thought it was a kind of new classification of state because the manual did not explain, and that it belonged to kernel.
I would like to know what is this `I` state and when it was created?

I do not mean `l` state which denotes for 'the process is multithreaded'.
I am running it on latest archlinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps` queries procfs - `/proc/[PID]/stat` - for the process state. [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says:

> /proc/[pid]/stat
>
> ```
>          Status information about the process.  This is used by ps(1).
>          It is defined in the kernel source file fs/proc/array.c.
> ```

And [`fs/proc/array.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/fs/proc/array.c#L135) says those tasks are idle.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.
I really would like to see more deeply about the kernel src.